# Can only display array by iterating through a for loop

Tags: c#

Hello I am trying to make a C# program that downloads files but I am having trouble with the array.

I have it split up the text for downloading and put it into a 2 level jagged array (string[][]).

Now I split up the rows up text by the | char so each line will be formatted like so:
{filename}|{filedescription}|{filehttppath}|{previewimagepath}|{length}|{source}

when I use short test text to put it into a text box it displays fine in the text box.

IE: a string like test|test|test|test|test|test

but if I put in a real string that I would actually be using for the program to DL files the only way I get the string to display is to iterate through it with a for or foreach loop.  If I try to access the data with the index I get an index missing error. (IE array[0])

So this is the code that gets the array to display:

```
public Form2(string[][] textList, string path)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + path + Environment.NewLine;
    WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
    foreach (string[] i in textList)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<i.Length;j++)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + i[j] + Environment.NewLine + @"\\newline" + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
}
```

And then this is the code that gives an index missing error:

```
public Form2(string[][] textList, string path)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + path + Environment.NewLine;
    WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
    foreach (string[] i in textList)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + i[0] + Environment.NewLine;
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + i[1] + Environment.NewLine;
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + i[2] + Environment.NewLine;
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + i[3] + Environment.NewLine;
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + i[4] + Environment.NewLine;
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + i[5] + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

Any help is this is apreciated I don't see why I can access they data through a for loop but not directly it just doesn't make any sense to me.

Also, here is the code that generates the array:

```
public String[][] finalList(string[] FileList)
{
    String[][] FinalArray = new String[FileList.Length][];
    for (int i = 0; i<FinalArray.Length;i++)
    {
        string[] fileStuff = FileList[i].Split(new char[] {'|'});
        FinalArray[i] = fileStuff;
    }
    return FinalArray;
}
```

Comment: Is the `Length` of `string[] i` > 1?

Comment: I would have to assume that there aren't 6 items in the `i` array.

Comment: index missing error ?? is it smth like "index out of range" ??

Comment: yes index out of range but I know the index is there because when I go through it with the for loop it displays them no problem but when I try to access the data directly I get the error.  When I loop for it displays all 6 values

Comment: which line is the error occurring on?

Comment: Error occurs on::
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + i[1] + Environment.NewLine;

Comment: Also when iterating through the for loop and add:: @"\\newline" + Environment.NewLine;  ad the end of each string made be each iteration so I know they aren't all getting stored into index 0 because each new index when looking is separated by "\\newline" in the results textBox so I know that it is the next array index

Comment: And if I try to combine the two methods so that it loops through and displays in the textbox and then displays in the textbox by accessing the index directly I no longer get an error but no text is displayed at all.

Comment: I did not get an error when I called your methods from a unit test

Comment: Yes, they work with test values for me to.  Unfortunatly I cannot post the real text for getting the files from my sponsors as I don't think it's something I am allowed to give out.  I think that something in the formating of the real links throuws the proccess off.  I'm almost done with the work around I'll post the results of it in a couple minutes

Comment: could it be failing on the last iteration if there was some extra space at end of input that is taken as a new file?

Comment: Okay when I leave the last part of the text out it works no problem.  It's the very end of the text or the [source] part of the end of the element that causes the problem.  So it is the sixth part of the array that seems to break it.  Could this be from it being to long?  Thanks for that suggestion I'm going to run a couple more tests as I cannot use a loop to do what I am trying to do because of variable scope.

Comment: i'll put the sample I ran in my answer below - good luck.

Comment: I'm about to try your sample.  For some reason when I have a sixth element in the array it fails on index 1 but when I remove that it works fine.

Comment: Okay it randomly works when I remember the last element but if I close the program and reopen it again it will just suddenly stop working again.

Comment: Okay It got it working.  For some reason the program was trying to process the blank lines bellow the text as well which is what was throwing the error.

Comment: yes that happens whitespace can be tricky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first example you are using the actual length of each inner array to do the concatenation.  In your second example you are hard coded to the same length yet you said in the intro it was a jagged array.

Can you show what your input text looks like?

you are not doing the same concatenation in first and second example so the resulting stings are very different.

```
        first = "\r\n Crazy Video\r\n\\\\newline\r\nThis Video is absolutly crazy!\r\n\\\\newline\r\nhtt://fakeurl.fake/vidfolder/video.flv\r\n\\\\newline\r\nhtt://fakeurl.fake/imgfolder/img.j‌​pg\r\n\\\\newline\r\n300\r\n\\\\newline\r\nhtt://fakeurl.fake \r\n\\\\newline\r\n"

        second = "\r\n Crazy Video\r\nThis Video is absolutly crazy!\r\nhtt://fakeurl.fake/vidfolder/video.flv\r\nhtt://fakeurl.fake/imgfolder/img.j‌​pg\r\n300\r\nhtt://fakeurl.fake \r\n" 


using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace ClassLibrary5
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [Test]
        public void test()
        {
            var temp = new[]
                           {
                               " Crazy Video|This Video is absolutly crazy!|htt://fakeurl.fake/vidfolder/video.flv|htt://fakeurl.fake/imgfolder/img.j‌​pg|300|htt://fakeurl.fake "
                           };
            var final = finalList(temp);
            var first = Form1(final, "path");
            var second = Form2(final, "path");
            Assert.IsTrue(first.CompareTo(second) == 0);
        }

        public string Form1(string[][] textList, string path)
        {
            string textString = path + Environment.NewLine;

            foreach (string[] i in textList)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < i.Length; j++)
                {
                    textString = textString + i[j] + Environment.NewLine + @"\\newline" + Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
            return textString;
        }

        public string Form2(string[][] textList, string path)
        {
            string textString = path + Environment.NewLine;

            foreach (string[] i in textList)
            {
                textString = textString + i[0] + Environment.NewLine;
                textString = textString + i[1] + Environment.NewLine;
                textString = textString + i[2] + Environment.NewLine;
                textString = textString + i[3] + Environment.NewLine;
                textString = textString + i[4] + Environment.NewLine;
                textString = textString + i[5] + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            return textString;
        }

        public String[][] finalList(string[] FileList)
        {
            String[][] FinalArray = new String[FileList.Length][];
            for (int i = 0; i < FinalArray.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] fileStuff = FileList[i].Split(new char[] {'|'});
                FinalArray[i] = fileStuff;
            }
            return FinalArray;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the test input text that works just fine that I used for testing while writing it was strings like test|test|test|test|test|test
the final strings is like 
Crazy Person Video|This video shows someone doing something crazy|http://fakeurl.fake/videofolders/video.flv|http://fakeurl.fake/imgfolder/img.jpg|300|http://fakeurl.fake

Comment: okay it cut off the final string I try this again::
Crazy Video|This Video is absolutly crazy!|htt://fakeurl.fake/vidfolder/video.flv|htt://fakeurl.fake/imgfolder/img.jpg|300|htt://fakeurl.fake

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure each `String[]` in `string[][] textList` has 6 elements?

Comment: Yes, 100% sure I enter the strings manually in a text box before proccessing them.
the string test|test|test|test|test|test works find but when I put in actual values rather than test ones it stop working unless I iterate through a loop instead of accessing them directly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace:

```
  for(int j=0;j<i.Length;j++)
     {
         textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + i[j] + Environment.NewLine + @"\\newline" + Environment.NewLine;
     }
```

with:

```
 for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
     {
         textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + i[j] + Environment.NewLine + @"\\newline" + Environment.NewLine;
     }
```

And see if you get the same result.  Your middle one has different logic than your first one.  To troubleshoot, first make the logic the same, and then continue troubleshooting from there.

Comment: Okay I now get the same out of index error after adding in J<6 I'm not sure why I'm still new to C#